# can I assert at compile-time that a user of my function has done something?

Tags: c++

I am building some library functions, one of which is basically a timer class with an arbitrary key. It looks conceptually like this:

```
template <typename Key>
class Timer
{
  void tic(Key key) {tics[key] = std::clock();
  void toc(Key key)
  {
    // calling this before tic has been called is fine
    if (!tic.find(key))
      tocs[key] = 0;
    else
      tocs[key] = std::clock() - tics[key];

    // BUT: writing code that calls "tocs" without ever calling "tics" should trigger
    // a compile-time error! How do I do this? Is it possible?
  }
  private:
  std::map<Key,clock_t> tics;
  std::map<Key,clock_t> tocs;
}
```

The task of this class is just to measure the time between `tic` and `toc` calls for each key. It should be perfectly legal to call `toc` before `tic` in order to allow the class to measure time *between* function calls, for example. However, calling a `tic` or a `toc` without some corresponding toc/tic in other parts of the code simply makes no sense, so it's obviously a coding error - which I would like to report at compile-time.

So, this should be ok:

```
Timer<int> timer;

while (1)
{
  timer.toc(0);
  // this reports the time elapses between the while 
  // loop ending and the while loop starting
  timer.tic(1);
}
```

but these should generate compile-time errors (well, warnings would be more suitable):

```
Timer<int> timer;

while (1)
{
  timer.toc(1); // this will always return 0
  timer.tic(0); // this is an unused initialization
}
```

Is it possible to achieve this? I suspect the answer is *no* but I wanted to make sure, because it would be really neat.

Comment: Detecting a run-time error at compile time? Now there's a trick. If a compiler could do this it could predict the output and there'd be no need to run the program.

Comment: This can be done *if* the information is encoded in the types - for instance, imagine there is a type `tick` that has the method `tock`. One must first get (at least an expression of) this type before one can `tock` it. Of course, it may be impractical and does prevent against bad `tick` objects (such as one that have already been `tock`ed). Otherwise, code coverage and unit tests can help increase confidence!

Comment: @MikeW I think I didn't clarify what I was doing in that first post, I've updated it with some examples to clarify.

Comment: @user2864740 the issue is that I want calls to `toc` before `tic` has been initialized to be *legal*, I just want the `tic` to be used if it is declared, and the `toc` to correspond to a `tic` even though it might be called before the corresponding `toc` at run-time

Comment: If something is not to be used in a certain way, see that it cannot be used that way by design instead of creating errors. Another and much more annoying version of this would be creating weird tricky documentations on how to use the functions.

Comment: @Etherealone I don't see how I can do this.

Comment: I've added some description as to why I want it to function this way, if that helps.

Comment: @ausairman I would simply keep an internal variable that updates itself calculating the time difference between the last tick and the new `tick` is called and there would not be any need to call `toc`. Just use two `tick`s then read that variable.

Comment: @Etherealone that's clever. I'll do that, thanks :)

Comment: The compiler can't enforce your requirement, because a call to one of your functions (let's say `tic()`) might be inside an `if` statement with an arbitrarily hard or even uncomputable condition, e.g. `if (program_will_eventually_halt(cin)) { tic(); }`.

Comment: @j_random_hacker ok, that's good to know - I just wasn't sure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you liked the proposition in comments, here is an example:

```
template<typename Key>
class Timer
{
 class CachePair
 {
  clock_t lastTimestamp, diff;

 public:
  CachePair() :
   lastTimestamp(0), diff(0)
  { }

  void update()
  {
   clock_t now = std::clock();
   diff = now - lastTimestamp;
   lastTimestamp = now;
  }
 };

 std::map<Key, CachePair> cache;

public:
 Timer()
 { }

 void tick(Key const& key)
 {
  cache[key].update();
 }

 clock_t const& value(Key const& key)
 {
  return cache[key].diff;
 }
};
```

Did not test it. This could be improved if you are using C++11 to avoid initialization in `CachePair` constructor when you are calling `update(Key)` for the first time on a `Key`.

Actually you can even eliminate the second variable if size matters *that* much and also eliminate much of the complication.

```
template<typename Key>
class Timer
{    
 std::map<Key, clock_t> cache;

public:
 Timer()
 { }

 clock_t tick(Key const& key)
 {
  clock_t& val = cache[key];

  clock_t now = std::clock();
  val = now; //this will update the value in map because it is defined as a reference to the variable in map
  return now - val;
 }
};
```

Way simpler huh, naturally better because has easier interface / less methods. You just need to type `size_t timeElapsed = timer.tick(key);` to get the time elapsed between two ticks.